# How can I view (not download) iPhone pictures on a Mac screen?

Tags: iphone, photos, airplay

I have an iPhone 5 with various photos.
I have a Mac desktop running OS X Yosemite.

Is there a way to view a fullscreen slideshow of the photos on the Mac display?  I don't want to download the photos, just flip through them for display on the big screen.

Comment: check this out http://www.airserver.com/

Answer (score 1):

Apple's mandated solution would be to wait for the photos to upload to your Photo Stream or iCloud Photo Library, then start a slideshow in iPhoto or Aperture.

Alternatively, you could make your Mac into an AirPlay receiver using a 3rd party app such as AirSquirrel's [Reflector](http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/). This one is paid, but I'm not aware of any free equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

To view the pictures on the camera roll on your iPhone:
  1. Plug in your iPhone to your Mac.
  2. Open iPhoto.
  3. Your iPhone appears in the Devices list on the iPhoto sidebar.
  4. Browse your pictures.

iPhoto does not provide a slideshow of the pictures on your iPhone, though.